# keeping data in nested hash table is a good sign for both memory management and better performance

Tags: java, object, collections, garbage-collection

I have to get some better opinion or an answer from you that to tackle the problem regarding data handling through **collection object/s** and **performance issue**.

Here I'am fetching data from around **5 to 6 lakh rows** to keep it into collection object from that I need to go very specific to each category filters to reach selected data,generally I took **vector** if I want to go any exact data, I should traverse every index of it. Due to this it slows my performance.

Instead of it I have a plan that **hash table** going to keep **a key** and itself as **a value another hash table**, similar it will grow nested way many hast tables. This is good for better solution or not, this is my common question.

**Note:** Every row contains around 15 to 17 columns(many be as array) in a oracle database.(those 6 lakh entries)

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Can you rephrase? Also the bold fonts in between are very distracting. Please re-format!

Comment: please consider posting the question in better format next time

Comment: Define 'better'. I can't see any positive benefit from your 2nd suggestion, and a lot of extra coding complication. I would also question why you are keeping half a million items in memory at all. You should be using the database for this: that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, a hash table (either `Hashtable` or `HashMap`) gives good lookup performance (O(1)), but consumes a significant amount of memory.  The memory overhead is in the region of 8 words per entry ... in addition to the space of the key and value.

Using a hash table to speed up lookup of records is a reasonable tradeoff.  However, using a hashtable to represent the fields of a record is a bad idea.  You would be better off using a custom class with a field for each column of the table.

However, EJP's comment is also pertinent.  You should consider performing your queries against the database.  In many respects, this is better thabn building an in-memory copy of the data and indexes and implementing your own query infrastructures.